# Switching from Nouveau -> Proprietary Nvidia Driver forces Lowlatency Kernel

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics, 20.04

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 Beta with the 3rd-party driver installation option checked. After the installation completed successfully and I had to restart, I used `nomodeset` in order to boot successfully. At this point in time, I had `5.4.0-25-generic` as my kernel version, and the open source driver selected (as a result of `nomodeset`).

I then went into "Additional Drivers" to switch from the open source driver to Nvidia's proprietary 440 drivers. After the changed got applied, I was asked to restart. After restarting and booting back into Ubuntu, I see that the selected driver is the proprietary one I chose earlier, but my kernel is now `5.4.0-25-lowlatency`. It somehow got added to the list of installed kernels at index 0 (value of `GRUB_DEFAULT`), even though I never installed it. When booting into specifically `5.4.0-25-generic` through the GRUB menu, my GPU (an RTX 2060) isn't recognized (and, for example, the display ends up being low resolution). Only with this implcitily installed `5.4.0-25-lowlatency` does my GPU get recognized.

Is this an expected compatibility issue between the generic kernel releases and Nvidia proprietary drivers? My intent here is to be able to install Nvidia's proprietary drivers along with the generic kernel, seeing that I don't do work which would benefit from the lowlatency one.

If it is a compatibility issue, why would the kernel being `lowlatency` suddenly resolve it, if it's still the same version (`5.4.0-25`)?

Comment: That is very strange, the https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/nvidia-driver-440 package does not have any kernel dependencies...